# Why is it necessary to prevent direct access to included files?

Tags: php

Why is it necessary to prevent direct access to included files? For example:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}
```

I notice many plugins do this but I don't see it in WordPress core files (such as [capabilities.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/capabilities.php) for example).

Answer (score 1):

Because you could have code that alters the database, shows sensitive information or otherwise trigger events you only want it to execute under the conditions you design without error.

Many core files only hold functions which don't execute if the file is accessed directly.

When they do alter data/files they usually check for $_POST actions, [Nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) and verify user permissions before actions are taken. Often times the permissions check is the first thing in the file.

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'list_users' ) ) {

if ( ! current_user_can( 'create_users' ) && ! current_user_can('promote_users' ) ) { wp_die

if ( ! defined( 'IFRAME_REQUEST' ) && isset( $_GET['action'] ) && in_array( $_GET['action'], array( 'update-selected', 'activate-plugin', 'update-selected-themes' ) ) ) 

if ( !current_user_can('export') )
```

If those checks fail they typically terminate the request

```
wp_die(__('You do not have sufficient permissions to export the content of this site.'));
```

Comment: In that case, may I ask why WordPress core doesn't do this?

Comment: I think you would have to look at them on a case by case basis. Many just hold functions that won't execute. Others verify logged in users, check $_POST, and verify nonces before doing something. Including an `ABSPATH` check is only ONE way to say, "hopefully this files was included in another file"

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, WordPress core never implements an `ABSPATH` or an `ABSPATH`-like check. I'm wondering why?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So are you saying if a file's code is designed with security in mind, the `ABSPATH` check is redundant (WordPress core files being an example of this)?

Comment: Correct, the ABSPATH just is a suuuper simple check for 1 single method of access. It's like closing your front door at night.